# Dealing with this error Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected '-&gt;' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Tags: php, angularjs

i found this code on the web

```
 <?php  

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "testing");  
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); 

 if(count($data) > 0) {  
      $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->firstname);       
      $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->lastname);  
      $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_user(first_name, last_name) VALUES 
           ('$first_name', '$last_name')";  
      $query = "INSERT INTO addstudent(id_num,fname, initial, lname, gender) 
         VALUES('$idnum',$fname','$initial','$lname','$gender')";
      if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))  
      {  
           echo "Data Inserted...";  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           echo 'Error';  
      }  
  }  
?>
```

and i added and changed some parts of the code into something like this:

```
 <?php  

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "thesisAppdb");  
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input")); 

 if(count($data) > 0) {  
      $idnum = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->idNum);
      $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->fname);
      $initial = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, data->initial);
      $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, data->lname);
      $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, data->gender);
      $query = "INSERT INTO addstudent(id_num,fname, initial, lname, gender) 
           VALUES('$idnum',$fname','$initial','$lname','$gender')";
      if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))  
      {  
           echo "Data Inserted...";  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           echo 'Error';  
      }
 }  
?>
```

and got an error

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in **C:\xampp\htdocs\thesisApp\db\addstudent.php** on line **9**

here is the controller

```
.controller('addStudentCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $mdToast, $http, 
 $mdSidenav) { 
 $scope.addStudent = function(){
    $http.post('db/addstudent.php', {
        'idNum': $scope.idNum,
        'fname': $scope.fname,
        'initial': $scope.initial,
        'lname': $scope.lname,
        'gender': $scope.gender
    }).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.idNum = '';
        $scope.fname = '';
        $scope.initial = '';
        $scope.lname = ''; 
        $scope.gender = '';
    });

}
})
```

hope i could get a response thanks.

Comment: Don't rely on `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to prevent SQL injection, [it alone is not sufficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string). You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your missing the `$` sign in front of your variable on line 9 also do that for the 2 lines below this line.

`$initial = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, data->initial);
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, data->lname);
$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, data->gender);`

change to

`$initial = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->initial);
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->lname);
$gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->gender);`

Comment: Why the -1 though?

Comment: @ka_lin Not to sure to be honest.

Comment: @user:2618034 thanks man. i can't believed i missed that but thank you really